# Ubuntu Touch - Voice Recognition

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is there a way I can activate speech recognition in the browser on Ubuntu Touch?

Or does this feature not exist yet? Are there plans to add it in the near future then?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here, it would appear that voice recognition is close vut not quite here yet [Is there speech recognition in Ubuntu for phones?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263098/is-there-speech-recognition-in-ubuntu-for-phones)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that. I have also seen this that looks like it may be the way to go. GoogletoUbuntu, using the Google Speech API's [LINUX SPEECH RECOGNITION USING GOOGLE SPEECH API: GOOGLE2UBUNTU](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/linux-speech-recognition-using-google.html). I will have a look at this and see if I can get it working.